# $SO(N)$ model and Noether current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

This is a very simple calculation that, for some reason, I cannot find the solution to. I want to show that along the equation of motion for the following $SO(N)$ model $$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi_i\partial^\mu\phi_i-\mu^2\phi_i\phi_i-g(\phi_i\phi_i)^2$$ the Nöether current $$J_\mu^a = \partial_\mu\phi_i\lambda^a_{ij}\phi_k$$ is conserved $$\partial^\mu J_\mu^a=0.$$

The progress I've made, which is a bit embarrassing to be honest, is up to this point: I found the EOM $$(\square+2\mu^2) \phi_i =-4g(\phi_j\phi_j) \phi_i$$ and that $$\partial^\mu J_\mu^a = \square\phi_i\lambda^a_{ij}\phi_j+\partial^\mu\phi_i\lambda^a_{ij}\partial_\mu\phi_j$$ Now I don't know where to go. Surely there's some trickery tied to the exchange of some partial derivatives throwing away boundary terms and so on, but I cannot see how.

Comment: You are there: $\lambda^a_{ij}$ is antisymmetric in i and j for this group, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, they are. Should I explicitly write the term as an antisymmetric combination? But I don't see how this could help with the equation of motion.

Comment: You supplant the d'Alembertian with something times $\phi_i$ in the last expression, so you have λ antisymmetric dotting on a symmetric tensor. QED.

Comment: @CosmasZachos But wouldn't this mean that $\partial_\mu J^\mu_a\times\text{something} = 0$ rather than $\partial_\mu J^\mu_a = 0$? Moreover, where the EOM would be used? Seems like the proposed solution would only make use of the fact that the generator of $\mathfrak{so}(N)$ are antisymmetric

Comment: Ohw ok, I think I get it. If I explicitly take from the EOM $\square \phi_i = -2\mu^2\phi_i-3g\phi^2\phi_i$ and use it in $\partial_\mu J^\mu_a$ then all terms would be zero since they'll be proportional to $\phi_i\phi_j$ or $\partial\phi_i\partial\phi_j$

Comment: In your last equation you used the EOM to supplant the d'Alembertian. Indeed, it is the symmetry structure of the EOMs that is utilized--their particular details don't matter.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, that's clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give a more general approach. Recall the basic setup of Noether's theorem. If $\delta\phi_i$ is *any* variation of the fields of your theory you have $$\delta{\cal L}=\dfrac{\partial\cal L}{\partial \phi_i}\delta\phi_i+\dfrac{\partial\cal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi_i)}\partial_\mu\delta\phi_i+\cdots+\dfrac{\partial \cal L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu_1}\cdots\partial_{\mu_k}\phi_i)}\partial_{\mu_1}\cdots\partial_{\mu_k}\delta \phi_i\tag{1}.$$

Now you can use Liebnitz rule several times on (1) to remove derivatives from $\delta \phi_i$ and extract terms proportional to $\delta \phi_i$ that combine with the first term in (1). Doing this reveals the general structure of $\delta{\cal L}$:$$\delta{\cal L}=E_i\delta\phi_i+\partial_\mu\Theta^\mu\tag{2},$$

where $E_i$ are the equations of motion and $\Theta^\mu[\phi_i;\delta\phi_i]$ depends on the fields and the specific variation. We call $\Theta^\mu$ the pre-sympletic potential current density and it takes one important role in the Covariant Phase Space formalism.

Now suppose that $\delta \phi_i$ is a (quasi-)symmetry of your Lagrangian. This means that if $\phi_i$ is a field configuration (not necessarily on-shell) then $\delta{\cal L}=\partial_\mu k^\mu$. If $k^\mu=0$ we have a real symmetry (not a quasi-symmetry), but Noether's theorem applies to both of them. In either case applying (2) to this specific variation you find that $$E_i\delta\phi_i+\partial_\mu\Theta^\mu=\partial_\mu k^\mu\Longrightarrow \partial_\mu(\Theta^\mu-k^\mu)=-E_i\delta \phi_i\tag{3}$$

and therefore setting $j^\mu = \Theta^\mu-k^\mu$ you find that *if the configuration about which you have taken the variation obeys the equations of motion $E_i$ vanishes and so does $\partial_\mu j^\mu$ giving current conservation*. Equality modulo equations of motion is often written as $\approx$ so that you might say that $\partial_\mu j^\mu \approx 0$.

This is Noether's first theorem. Now apply this to your Lagrangian. First find $\Theta^\mu$ by taking $\delta {\cal L}$. If you do so you will recognize that $\Theta^\mu[\phi_i;\delta\phi_i]:=\partial^\mu \phi_i \delta \phi_i$.

Now I believe you are OK in verifying that ${\cal L}$ is invariant under ${\rm SO}(N)$, in which case that Noether's theorem applies. Now consider the infinitesimal ${\delta}_{{\rm SO}(N)}\phi_i$ transformation. If $\phi_i$ is a multiplet transforming in a representation with generators $T^a$ we can write ${\delta}_{{\rm SO}(N)}\phi_i=\omega^a (T^a)_{ij}\phi_j$. In that case we have $$\Theta^\mu[\phi_i;\delta_{{\rm SO}(N)} \phi_i]=\partial^\mu \phi_i \delta_{{\rm SO}(N)}\phi_i=\omega^a\partial^\mu \phi_i (T^a)_{ij}\phi_j\tag{4}.$$

Noether's theorem implies that (4) is conserved on-shell for all $\omega^a$. In particular taking $\omega^a = \delta^{ab}$ for each value of $b$, one at a time, we obtain $$J_\mu^{a}=\partial_\mu \phi_i (T^a)_{ij}\phi_j\tag{5},$$

and you have found through Noether's theorem the statement of the conservation of $J_\mu^{a}$, modulo equations of motion of course, $\partial^\mu J_\mu^a\approx 0$. Assuming $\lambda^a_{ij}$ in your question are the matrix elements of the generators in the representation $\phi_i$ lives this is exactly the current you want to prove to be conserved.

Comment: Wow that's a really cool way of doing the calculation. Never heard of *pre-sympletic potential current density*, I've seen many proof of Nöether's theorem but none of them seem so general like yours. Very cool. Thank you!

Comment: @DavideMorgante If you're interested in learning more about the covariant phase space formalism used in this answer, you might like this paper: [Covariant phase space with boundaries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08616) (`https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08616`). It's well-written and thorough.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I'll surely give it a read! Thank you.

Comment: @user1620696 Thank you as well!